# jQuery Animated Scroll Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm trying to get a jQuery animated scroll function working so when a user clicks a button, it scrolls down nicely. I've worked through several tutorials and I can't get the animation to work. When I click on the button, it jumps to the respective area but it is sudden and there isn't any animation. Here is my code:

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
          if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') &&  location.hostname == this.hostname) {
             var target = $(this.hash);
             target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
             if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                   scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
             return false;
             }
           }
       });
   });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-inline intro-social-buttons">

   <li><a href="#moreinfo" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-rocket fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Learn More</span></a>
   </li>

</ul>
```

and then later on:

```
<div class="content-section-a" id="moreinfo">
```

Both jquery-1.10.2.js and jQuery.min.map are linked and load without a problem. What did I do wrong??

Answer (score 3):

This may be the problem:

`target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');`

The default for a HTML anchor is to jump to an element with the name / id after the "#".

Shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/avBst/1/

Which could mean your target var is not actually returning an item and jQuery animate code not firing at all.

---

Here is simple code to scroll to a specified div with id "at_bottom" and a link back to the top.

http://jsfiddle.net/xUs6g/4/

More "one-fits-all" answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/UGfDj/1/

*Explanation:*

Create a link with a custom attribute:

`<a class="scroll_to" data-more-info="section_one">Go To Section One</a>`

and a div with a matching ID

`<div id="section_one" class="section">`

When that link is clicked, extract the attribute value and scroll to the div with that ID.

```
$("a.scroll_to").click(function() {
  var target = $(this).attr("data-more-info");
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#"+target).offset().top - 50 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

The -50 is to offset the top margin in the fiddle. You probably won't need it.

This way you won't need to write click functions for all of your scroll buttons etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy CSS solution [but it's not available on all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_scroll-behavior).
I recommend one of the jquery answers but this a neat css trick that saved my life I felt inclined to share :)

```css
html,body {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```